# rails sort of 2 dimensional array does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I have a 2d array which is supposed to be a user ranking, based on points. I first init it:

```
ranked_user = []
```

Then I do some points calculations and push some stuff into the array:

```
ranked_user.push([user.id, user.username, user.location, points])
```

which results in

```
=> [[8, "Jhonny", "Berlin", 11], [9, "Ben", "Hamburg", 3], [10, "Hugo", "Munich", 6]]
```

now I want to sort that array based on the 4th value (points) in order to show the ranking.
I've tried two things:

```
ranked_user.sort_by{|k|k[3]}
```

and

```
ranked_user.sort { |a, b| b[3] <=> a[3] }
```

I expect this:

```
=> [[9, "Ben", "Hamburg", 3], [10, "Hugo", "Munich", 6], [8, "Jhonny", "Berlin", 11]]
```

but the array simply is not sorted.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Somehow, if I put that into an each loop it does work. If I plot it out in plain, it remains unsorted.

Comment: What do you mean? You must also remember that this doesn't change the array, if that is what you want you can use `sort_by!`

Comment: Iceman is right, just use sort_by! or just save the sorted array to a new local variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add on to Morgan Laco's answer :

If you do :

```
ranked_user.sort_by{|k|k[3]}
```

Then `ranked_user` would still be unordered. Only the return is ordered.

So in order to change `ranked_user`, you would have to do either of these :

```
ranked_user = ranked_user.sort_by{|k|k[3]}
ranked_user.sort_by!{|k|k[3]}
```

Comment: ty - guess that was my mistake

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `sort_by!` in order to modify the original array.